# How to access the child class through the parent class object with shared pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, linked-list, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a linked list using a parent `Node` class and a child Node class (called `Transaction`). The linked list class (called `Ledger`) is using shared pointers to access the `Node` and `Transaction` class.

My goal is to use the `<<` operator with a shared pointer of `Node`, called `endPtr` (the linked list uses a `tail` instead of a `head`, going from last to first), and traverse each `Node` instance and access the `Transaction` class variables of that parent `Node` and print them out.

This is my `Node` header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node {
protected:
    shared_ptr<Node> prev;
    string nodeType;
public:
    Node();
    Node(shared_ptr<Node>);

    shared_ptr<Node> getPrev() const;
    void setPrev(shared_ptr<Node>);
    string getType();
};
```

My `Transaction` header file that inherits from `Node`:

```
#pragma once
#include "Node.h"

class Transaction: public Node {
private:
    string toName;
    string fromName;
    int amount;
public:
    Transaction();
    Transaction(string, string, int);


    string getToName() const;
    string getFromName() const;
    int getAmount() const;

    void setToName(string);
    void setFromName(string);
    void setAmount(int);

    shared_ptr<Transaction> getPrev();
    void setPrev(shared_ptr<Transaction>);
};
```

And this is the `Ledger` header and cpp files:

```
class Ledger {
private:
    string toName;
    string fromName;
    int amount;
    vector<pair<string, int>> ledgerVector;
    shared_ptr<Node> endPtr;
    int count = 0;
public:
    Ledger();

    Ledger& operator+=(Transaction);
    Ledger& operator-=(shared_ptr<Transaction>);
    void Add(Transaction);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Ledger&);
};
```

cpp:

```
Ledger& Ledger::operator+=(Transaction newTxn) {
    shared_ptr<Transaction> newTransaction = make_shared<Transaction>(newTxn);
    shared_ptr<Node> newPointer = make_shared<Node>(newTxn);

    if (endPtr != nullptr) {
        newPointer->setPrev(endPtr);
        endPtr = newPointer;
    }
    else
        endPtr = newPointer;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Ledger& ledger) {
    weak_ptr<Node> newNode = ledger.endPtr;
    auto node = newNode.lock();
    while (node != nullptr) {
        if (node->getType() == "TRANSACTION") {
            shared_ptr<Transaction> transNode = make_shared<Transaction>(node.get());
            string fromName = transNode->getFromName();
            cout << fromName << endl;
        }
        node = node->getPrev();
    }
}
```

Finally, `main.cpp`:

```
Transaction t1 = Transaction("Albert", "Bob", 100);
Transaction t2 = Transaction("James", "Alice", 50);
Ledger myLedger;
myLedger += t1;
myLedger += t2;

cout << myLedger;
```

As you can see in the `+=` operator, that is how I'm adding new transaction nodes, by converting the `Transaction` into a smart pointer and then creating a `Node` smart pointer from the same `Transaction`. At which point, I've assigned it the `endPtr` of the `Ledger` class.

This is what the `endPtr` looks like, as seen through `Node` instances:

[image]

The `endPtr` has two `Node` instances, as attempted in the `main()`, but I have no idea if the content of the `Transaction` is stored in them as well, nor do I know how to access it.

I understand there is no reason to go about it this way, as it may not be optimal, but any guidance on accessing inherited class variables through a parent object instance while using smart pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ledger's `operator+=` (and presumably `Add()`) and `operator<<` are implemented incorrectly.  Try this instead:

```
class Ledger {
    ...
public:
    ...

    Ledger& operator+=(const Transaction&);
    ...
    void Add(const Transaction&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Ledger&);
};

void Ledger::Add(const Transaction &newTxn)
{
    auto newPointer = make_shared<Transaction>(newTxn);
    newPointer->setPrev(endPtr);
    endPtr = newPointer;
}

Ledger& Ledger::operator+=(const Transaction &newTxn) {
    Add(newTxn);
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Ledger& ledger) {
    auto node = ledger.endPtr;
    while (node != nullptr) {
        auto transNode = dynamic_pointer_cast<Transaction>(node);
        if (transNode != nullptr) {
            os << transNode->getFromName() << endl;
        }
        node = node->getPrev();
    }
    return os;
}
```